# Angular Changing the Color of a Row on Button Click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a long list of elements and a button for sidebar. Since the list is too long, I want to remember where I have clicked. For that, I want the row color to change on button click. Here's what I have done so far. I've only managed to change the color of the whole table (pool-row). What should I do to only change the color of the selected row?

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end" class="mat-elevation-z4 responsive-grid">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end" class="pr-4">
                    <mat-form-field fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="30">
                        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrele">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="stock-table" id="pool-row">
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Reference">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                            Belge No </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                            <p *ngIf="controlReferanceColor(row)" style="color:red;">{{row.Reference}}
                            </p>
                            <p *ngIf="!controlReferanceColor(row)">{{row.Reference}}</p>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Detay" *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id != 32"
                                [routerLink]="getLink(row)" target="_blank">
                                <mat-icon>open_in_browser</mat-icon>
                            </a>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Liste" *ngIf="row.SourceType?.Id == 32" id="list"
                                class="sidebar-toggle" (click)="getReferenceList('lab-test-detail-preview',row)">
                                <mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>                        
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                        [ngClass]="{'amber-fg': controlReferanceColor(row) == true}"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
getReferenceList(sidebarName: string, reference: IProcess) {
    if (reference && reference.Reference != "") {
        this.selectedProcessList = this._stockService.processList.find(
            (x) => x.Reference === reference.Reference
        ).ChildProcessList;
        this._fuseSidebarService.getSidebar(sidebarName).open();
    }
    document.getElementById('pool-row').style.backgroundColor = '#fced49';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say all you need to do is to pass in your ngFor index into the click function:

```
(click)="getReferenceList('lab-test-detail-preview',row, i)"
```

In the function you save it into a field of the component

```js
getReferenceList(sidebarName: string, reference: IProcess, index: number) {
  this.currentRow = index;
  // ...
}
```

And then apply styling (e.g. via applying a css class) in your template

```html
<tr mat-row 
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    [class.red]="currentRow === i"></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn' work :/

Comment: currentRow needs to be declared as a variable in your component. Maybe you should provide a code example on stackblitz because I think Stackoverflow is not there to debugg your application through comments, but to answer questions ;)

Answer (score -1):

As Andi-Io said, pass the index into `getReferenceList` and set a property.

```
currentRow: number = -1;
// or
currentRow: number | null = null;
// or
currentRow: number | undefined = undefined;

getReferenceList(sidebarName: string, reference: IProcess, index: number) {
  this.currentRow = index;
  // ...
}
```

(Remove the line with `document.getElementById`. You only ever want to manipulate the dom directly if not possible otherwise.)

Then in the template change the bottom line like this:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;"
  [ngClass]="{'amber-fg': controlReferanceColor(row) == true, 'cur-row': i === currentRow}"></tr>
```

Note: You need to grab the index again.

Declare the respective class in you scss/css file.

Comment: I don't have a `currentRow` property, where should I declare it?

Comment: In the typescript class (where `getReferenceList` is in).

Comment: Didn't work again. Now the whole list appears as yellow when the page first opens. And I didn't click on the button of a row.

Comment: Don't know why my answer basically gets copy and pasted by you @GunnarB.

Comment: @Andi-lo Your answer misses at least `let i = index` in the template and also OP already uses `ngClass` so you can append to that instead of using `class.X`. I also point out that you should not manipulate the dom directly.

Comment: @RocketMonkey `currentRow` should be initialized as `-1` or be of type `number | null` and initialized as `null`. Otherwise, as Andi-Io pointed out, we'd need to see updated code or a stackblitz to help you further.